# Insert LaTeX command after a character inside \texttt{}

Tags: macros, pdftex

Is it possible to parse the argument of a macro for a specified character and insert another LaTeX command after it?

I got this LaTeX source, which breaks the `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
Here comes some explaining about stuff and then this very Java class \texttt{java.text.SimpleDateFormat} must be used!
\end{document}
```

I was thinking of a macro, that inserts an `\allowbreak{}` after each dot.
Another solution, that achieves the desired result, is welcome as well.

Comment: url package `\path{java.text.SimpleDateFormat} ` (or use the facilities of that package to define a similar custome command specifically for java class names